# Istio blocking connection to MySQL

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I would like to deploy the [java petstore](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/jpetstore-kubernetes) for kubernetes. In order to achieve this I have **2 simple deployments**. The first one is the **java web app** and the second one is a **MySQL database**.

*When istio is disabled the connection between the app and the DB works well.

Unfortunatly when the istio sidecar is injected the communication between the two stops working.*

Here is the deployment file of the web app:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jpetstoreweb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jpetstoreweb
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jpetstoreweb
        image: wingardiumleviosa/petstore:v7
        env:
          - name: VERSION
            value: "1"
          - name: DB_URL
            value: "jpetstoredb-service"
          - name: DB_PORT
            value: "3306"
          - name: DB_NAME
            value: "jpetstore"
          - name: DB_USERNAME
            value: "jpetstore"
          - name: DB_PASSWORD
            value: "foobar"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9080
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 9080
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 5
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jpetstoreweb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: jpetstoreweb
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 9080
---
```

And next the deployment file of the mySql database :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jpetstoredb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jpetstoredb
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jpetstoredb
        image: wingardiumleviosa/petstoredb:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
        env:
          - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: "foobar"
          - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
            value: "jpetstore"
          - name: MYSQL_USER
            value: "jpetstore"
          - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
            value: "foobar"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jpetstoredb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: jpetstoredb
  ports:
  - port: 3306
    targetPort: 3306
```

Finally the error logs from the web app trying to connect to the DB :

```
Exception thrown by application class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest:488'
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: java.io.EOFException, underlying cause: null ** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** java.io.EOFException STACKTRACE: java.io.EOFException at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1395) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:1539) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:1930) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1168) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1279) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQuery(MysqlIO.java:1225) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2278) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2237) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2218) at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.setAutoCommit(Connection.java:548) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:331) at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:317) at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:221) at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:350) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:261) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:101) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171) at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171) at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy28.getCategory(Unknown Source) at org.springframework.samples.jpetstore.web.spring.ViewCategoryController.handleRequest(ViewCategoryController.java:31) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:874) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:808) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:476) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:431) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1255) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:743) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:440) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:182) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:93) at com.ibm.ws.security.jaspi.JaspiServletFilter.doFilter(JaspiServletFilter.java:56) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:201) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:996) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1134) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1005) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:75) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:927) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:279) at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:1023) at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.wrapHandlerAndExecute(HttpDispatcherLink.java:417) at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:376) at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:532) at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:466) at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:331) at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:70) at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:501) at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:571) at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:926) at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1015) at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:232) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:812) ** END NESTED EXCEPTION ** 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:488)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:431)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
```

Extract : `Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction`

---

**Additionnal info :**

1) I can curl the DB from the web app container using CURL and it answers correctly.

2) I use Cilium instead of Calico

3) I installed Istio using HELM

4) Kubernetes is installed on bare metal (no cloud provider)

5) `kubectl get pods -n istio-system` all istio pods are running

6) `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` all cilium pods are running

7) Istio is injected using `kubectl apply -f <(~/istio-1.0.5/bin/istioctl kube-inject -f ~/jpetstore.yaml) -n foo`. If I use any other method Istio is not injecting itself in the Web pod (But works for the DB pod, god knows why)

8) The DB pod is always happy and working well

9) Logs of the istio-proxy container inside the WebApp pod : `kubectl logs jpetstoreweb-84c7d8964-s642k istio-proxy -n myns`

```
2018-12-28T03:52:30.610101Z     info    Version root@6f6ea1061f2b-docker.io/istio-1.0.5-c1707e45e71c75d74bf3a5dec8c7086f32f32fad-Clean
2018-12-28T03:52:30.610167Z     info    Proxy role: model.Proxy{ClusterID:"", Type:"sidecar", IPAddress:"10.233.72.142", ID:"jpetstoreweb-84c7d8964-s642k.myns", Domain:"myns.svc.cluster.local", Metadata:map[string]string(nil)}
2018-12-28T03:52:30.611217Z     info    Effective config: binaryPath: /usr/local/bin/envoy
configPath: /etc/istio/proxy
connectTimeout: 10s
discoveryAddress: istio-pilot.istio-system:15007
discoveryRefreshDelay: 1s
drainDuration: 45s
parentShutdownDuration: 60s
proxyAdminPort: 15000
serviceCluster: jpetstoreweb
zipkinAddress: zipkin.istio-system:9411

2018-12-28T03:52:30.611249Z     info    Monitored certs: []envoy.CertSource{envoy.CertSource{Directory:"/etc/certs/", Files:[]string{"cert-chain.pem", "key.pem", "root-cert.pem"}}}
2018-12-28T03:52:30.611829Z     info    Starting proxy agent
2018-12-28T03:52:30.611902Z     info    Received new config, resetting budget
2018-12-28T03:52:30.611912Z     info    Reconciling configuration (budget 10)
2018-12-28T03:52:30.611926Z     info    Epoch 0 starting
2018-12-28T03:52:30.613236Z     info    Envoy command: [-c /etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev0.json --restart-epoch 0 --drain-time-s 45 --parent-shutdown-time-s 60 --service-cluster jpetstoreweb --service-node sidecar~10.233.72.142~jpetstoreweb-84c7d8964-s642k.myns~myns.svc.cluster.local --max-obj-name-len 189 --allow-unknown-fields -l warn --v2-config-only]
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.630][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:190] initializing epoch 0 (hot restart version=10.200.16384.256.options=capacity=16384, num_slots=8209 hash=228984379728933363 size=4882536)
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.631][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:192] statically linked extensions:
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.631][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:194]   access_loggers: envoy.file_access_log,envoy.http_grpc_access_log
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.631][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:197]   filters.http: envoy.buffer,envoy.cors,envoy.ext_authz,envoy.fault,envoy.filters.http.header_to_metadata,envoy.filters.http.jwt_authn,envoy.filters.http.rbac,envoy.grpc_http1_bridge,envoy.grpc_json_transcoder,envoy.grpc_web,envoy.gzip,envoy.health_check,envoy.http_dynamo_filter,envoy.ip_tagging,envoy.lua,envoy.rate_limit,envoy.router,envoy.squash,istio_authn,jwt-auth,mixer
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.631][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:200]   filters.listener: envoy.listener.original_dst,envoy.listener.proxy_protocol,envoy.listener.tls_inspector
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.631][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:203]   filters.network: envoy.client_ssl_auth,envoy.echo,envoy.ext_authz,envoy.filters.network.rbac,envoy.filters.network.thrift_proxy,envoy.http_connection_manager,envoy.mongo_proxy,envoy.ratelimit,envoy.redis_proxy,envoy.tcp_proxy,mixer
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.631][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:205]   stat_sinks: envoy.dog_statsd,envoy.metrics_service,envoy.stat_sinks.hystrix,envoy.statsd
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.631][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:207]   tracers: envoy.dynamic.ot,envoy.lightstep,envoy.zipkin
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.631][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:210]   transport_sockets.downstream: alts,envoy.transport_sockets.capture,raw_buffer,tls
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.631][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:213]   transport_sockets.upstream: alts,envoy.transport_sockets.capture,raw_buffer,tls
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.634][20][info][config] external/envoy/source/server/configuration_impl.cc:50] loading 0 static secret(s)
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.638][20][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:240] gRPC config stream closed: 14, no healthy upstream
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.638][20][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:41] Unable to establish new stream
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.638][20][info][config] external/envoy/source/server/configuration_impl.cc:60] loading 1 listener(s)
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.640][20][info][config] external/envoy/source/server/configuration_impl.cc:94] loading tracing configuration
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.640][20][info][config] external/envoy/source/server/configuration_impl.cc:103]   loading tracing driver: envoy.zipkin
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.640][20][info][config] external/envoy/source/server/configuration_impl.cc:116] loading stats sink configuration
[2018-12-28 03:52:30.640][20][info][main] external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:432] starting main dispatch loop
[2018-12-28 03:52:32.010][20][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:240] gRPC config stream closed: 14, no healthy upstream
[2018-12-28 03:52:32.011][20][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:41] Unable to establish new stream
[2018-12-28 03:52:34.691][20][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:240] gRPC config stream closed: 14, no healthy upstream
[2018-12-28 03:52:34.691][20][warning][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/config/grpc_mux_impl.cc:41] Unable to establish new stream
[2018-12-28 03:52:38.483][20][info][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:130] cm init: initializing cds
[2018-12-28 03:53:01.596][20][info][upstream] external/envoy/source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:494] add/update cluster outbound|443||kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local during init
```

**...**

```
[2018-12-28T04:09:09.561Z] - 115 1548 6 "127.0.0.1:9080" inbound|80||jpetstoreweb-service.myns.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:40318 10.233.72.142:9080 10.233.72.1:43098
[2018-12-28T04:09:14.555Z] - 115 1548 8 "127.0.0.1:9080" inbound|80||jpetstoreweb-service.myns.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:40350 10.233.72.142:9080 10.233.72.1:43130
[2018-12-28T04:09:19.556Z] - 115 1548 5 "127.0.0.1:9080" inbound|80||jpetstoreweb-service.myns.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:40364 10.233.72.142:9080 10.233.72.1:43144
[2018-12-28T04:09:24.558Z] - 115 1548 6 "127.0.0.1:9080" inbound|80||jpetstoreweb-service.myns.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:40378 10.233.72.142:9080 10.233.72.1:43158
```

10) Using Istio 1.0.5 and kubernetes 1.13.0

All idears are welcome ;-)
Thx

Comment: You haven't included one byte of output from your Istio containers, nor its configuration, nor your CNI setup, nor anything that can help us to help you; you also haven't specified whether you can connect to mysql from anything other than the petstore Pod, or whether the MySQL Pods are healthy and happy

Comment: Could you please add more information about your cluster: what type is it (on premise, AWS,GCP,...), which way you installed it (kops,kubeadm,...), what networking add-on are you using(calico,flannel,...), which way you installed Istio (yaml, helm,...), do you use sidecar autoinjection and mTLS? Could you also add output of the command `kubeclt get all --all-namespaces -o wide`?

Comment: @VAS Thx for your answers. I'll add more data but as misfortune never comes one at a time, my cluster died...

Comment: I added some more info. Don't hesitate to ask for more ! Happy to comply... @VAS I didn't add the output of get all --all-namespace because its a test environment and its a comlete mayhem ;-)

Comment: It is stupid question yet how do you curl your database? Isn't it TCP? As I know, MySQL can't answer HTTP requests.

Comment: @Doctor Won't solve your problem but will save you some headaches. In Istio you need to name the service ports as explained here https://istio.io/help/faq/traffic-management/.
Do you have mTLS enabled?

Comment: @nurgasemetey When logging inside a container I CURL the DB and it responds with HTML so I guess It means that its using HTTP. On the other hand I suppose that the petstore connects to the DB using TCP !

Comment: @rinormaloku I'm using the default mTLS (mode: permissive) allowing HTTP and HTTPS requests !

Comment: Could you try without mTLS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there really is an issue with **Istio 1.0.5** and the **JDBC** of **MySQL**

The temporary solution is to delete the mesh ressource in the following way :

`kubectl delete meshpolicies.authentication.istio.io default`

As stated [here](https://github.com/retroryan/istio-workshop/issues/48) and referencing [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/10062).

(FYI : I deleted the ressource BEFORE deploying my petstore app.)

---

As of **Istio 1.1.1** there is more data on this problem in the [FAQ](https://istio.io/help/faq/security/#mysql-with-mtls)